# Jasper and JFree report compatible itext jar

Tags: java, itext, jfreechart

1. I am using both jasper and jfree reports in my project but both require different version    of jars
2. am using itext 2.1.7, but its not compatible with jfree

Comment: In Java you can use both an old-style (com.lowagie.*, versions before 5) and a new-style (com.itextpdf.*, versions 5.*) side by side, you only have to cope with the different BouncyCastle dependencies (old-style: BC up to 1.46, new-style BC 1.47 and up) which in turn differ a lot. Thus, unless you have to deal with encryption (including usage permissions) or signatures with both iText flavors, that is no problem. Otherwise you can change one iText flavor to use SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-requirements) provides info on compatibility versions. Check if you have these versions or not.

Comment: i am using itext 2.1.7 which is supporting for jasper, but not for jfree